# data.table loses factor ordering after rbind, R

Tags: r, sorting, data.table

When `rbind`ing two `data.table` with ordered factors, the ordering seems to be lost:

```
dtb1 = data.table(id = factor(c("a", "b"), levels = c("a", "c", "b"), ordered=T), key="id")
dtb2 = data.table(id = factor(c("c"), levels = c("a", "c", "b"), ordered=T), key="id") 
test = rbind(dtb1, dtb2)
is.ordered(test$id)
#[1] FALSE
```

Any thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`data.table` does some fancy footwork that means that `data.table:::.rbind.data.table` is called when `rbind` is called on objects including `data.tables`. `.rbind.data.table` utilizes the speedups associated with `rbindlist`, with a bit of extra checking to match by name etc.

`.rbind.data.table` deals with factor columns by using `c` to combine them (hence retaining the levels attribute)

```
# the relevant code is
l = lapply(seq_along(allargs[[1L]]), function(i) do.call("c", 
    lapply(allargs, "[[", i)))
```

In `base` `R` using `c` in this manner does not retain the "ordered" attribute, it doesn't even return a factor!

For example (in `base` `R`)

```
f <- factor(1:2, levels = 2:1, ordered=TRUE)
g <- factor(1:2, levels = 2:1, ordered=TRUE)
# it isn't ordered!
is.ordered(c(f,g))
# [1] FALSE
# no suprise as it isn't even a factor!
is.factor(c(f,g))
# [1] FALSE
```

However `data.table` has an S3 method `c.factor`, which is used to ensure that a factor is returned and the levels are retained. Unfortunately this method does not retain the ordered attribute.

```
getAnywhere('c.factor')
# A single object matching ‘c.factor’ was found
# It was found in the following places
#   namespace:data.table
# with value
# 
# function (...) 
# {
#     args <- list(...)
#     for (i in seq_along(args)) if (!is.factor(args[[i]])) 
#         args[[i]] = as.factor(args[[i]])
#     newlevels = unique(unlist(lapply(args, levels), recursive = TRUE, 
#         use.names = TRUE))
#     ind <- fastorder(list(newlevels))
#     newlevels <- newlevels[ind]
#     nm <- names(unlist(args, recursive = TRUE, use.names = TRUE))
#     ans = unlist(lapply(args, function(x) {
#         m = match(levels(x), newlevels)
#         m[as.integer(x)]
#     }))
    structure(ans, levels = newlevels, names = nm, class = "factor")
}
<bytecode: 0x073f7f70>
<environment: namespace:data.table
```

So yes, this is a bug.  It is now reported as [#5019](http://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5019&group_id=240&atid=975).

Comment: very good. just saw the bug email come through. thanks for digging in.

Comment: @mnel, the timing is unbelievable. Eddi is working on this and he just moved this from a [bug to a FR](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=978&aid=4856&group_id=240) after some discussions, yesterday. He should be updating this post soon. Your guess reg. solution was his as well.

Comment: @eddi, just tagging you, so that you can add the NEWS update after your fix.

Comment: thanks everyone, the `c.factor` function is actually going away soon and there will be a different solution for this, but details are still in the air. Retaining "correct" order is a non-trivial problem (and one that base completely messes up btw).

Comment: @mnel: how can you figure out which S3 method is being dispatched this case? for example how did you know that `rbind` was calling `.rbind.data.table`?

Comment: @Alex, loading `data.table` dynamically makes changes to `rbind.data.frame`. It inserts a couple of lines in the top to check if the input is a data.table and if so call `.rbind.data.table`. Load `data.table` and have a look at `rbind.data.frame` code.

Comment: @Arun: ahh got it! thank you. interesting.. when i did `methods(rbind)` only the `data.frame` one came up so i was a bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

As of [version 1.8.11](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&revision=1012&root=datatable) `data.table` will combine ordered factors to result in `ordered` if a global order exists, and will complain and result in a factor if it doesn't exist:

```
DT1 = data.table(ordered('a', levels = c('a','b','c')))
DT2 = data.table(ordered('a', levels = c('a','d','b')))

rbind(DT1, DT2)$V1
#[1] a a
#Levels: a < d < b < c

DT3 = data.table(ordered('a', levels = c('b','a','c')))
rbind(DT1, DT3)$V1
#[1] a a
#Levels: a b c
#Warning message:
#In rbindlist(lapply(seq_along(allargs), function(x) { :
#  ordered factor levels cannot be combined, going to convert to simple factor instead
```

To contrast, here's what base R does:

```
rbind(data.frame(DT1), data.frame(DT2))$V1
#[1] a a
#Levels: a < b < c < d
# Notice that the resulting order does not respect the suborder for DT2

rbind(data.frame(DT1), data.frame(DT3))$V1
#[1] a a
#Levels: a < b < c
# Again, suborders are not respected and new order is created
```

Answer (score -1):

I met with the same problem after `rbind`, just re-assign the ordered level for the column.

`test$id <- factor(test$id, levels = letters, ordered = T)`

It's better to define factor after `rbind`